# MSMQ: How can I create a private queue on a remote computer

Tags: c#, .net, msmq

I need to create a Private message queue on a Remote computer. All me research indicates this is not possible through the System.Messaging objects. Can anyone confirm/deny this. My other option is to create an addition service on the remote host that listens for requests to create queues and then creates them locally.

Any better/simpler ideas would be welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You can't and you shouldn't.**

MSMQ works like a mailbox, you only have to create an inbox, the outbox is created by MSMQ itself.

Indeed just create a sperate service that creates the queue on the remote machine, by installing it localy.

Comment: I ended up making a service to run create the private queues on the remote machine. Final pay-off from a queue stability point of view was worth it. No more AD-pain.

Answer (score 1):

You can't and its annoying. MSMQ is strange in the windows environment. there are allot of differences about what you can do locally and remotely. There is nothing reasonable to do about it. Just live with it.